# Fixed size database - advantage?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database that needs to support many INSERTs, UPDATEs and DELETEs.
The database keeps live data for last 3 months. The aount of data is huge - the size of the database is around 0.5TB.

Each day I run a process that archives older than 3 months data. Of course, deleting the data won't free up the resulted space. To reclaim the disk space I need to (auto)shrink the database. This of course is followed by (auto)grow when more database space is neded.

On the other hand we know that [shrinking the database is evil!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2007/03/28/turn-auto-shrink-off.aspx) 
One solution that crossed my mind is to set a fixed size for my database from 0.5TB to 0.8TB or even 0.9TB or whatever hoping that the free space resulted after archiving the data (that is delete older data) will be reused by the database later.

Can anyone confirm that this way I can avoid the need for (auto)shrink + (auto)growth? Of course, we assume that the fixed size is big enough.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set up a scheduled task to shrink the database every n days.

Fixed size is risky - easy to fill the database up, and block live access.

Comment: That's the big idea, I want to avoi shrinking/growing because during these operations the database is almost unusable

Comment: If you need to reclaim disk-space I don't see you have any alternative - just don't do it every day, and do it at minimum load time

Comment: But if my data stays in a 500GB database now and I set the db size to 900GB, and I delete everyday older data, why should I worry? The data itself will never have peaks higher than 600GB for example